# Alert requesting permission to open browser iOS-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-permissions

I have an application that logs in against keycloak. To do this, when starting the application an alert appears warning that my app wants to use "xxxxxplatform.com" for Sign In. It gives me 2 options: Cancel (the app would do nothing) and Continue (opens the platform browser to do the login).
My question is: is it necessary that this alert always appears? Or can it be added to the plist (or somewhere else) to always keep the permission granted? Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm using AppAuth for the login

Comment: No, it is a security feature of iOS.  It will always appear.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, I thought so!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.